# excel vba: use dynamically built string to define array of arrays (for .TextToColumns)

Tags: arrays, string, vba, excel

EDIT: The marked solution is correct. My problem was that I was incrementing the values I was using in the `FieldInfo` parameter of `.TextToColumns` rather than using absolute positions of splits
For Example:
`1, 3, 2, 5` instead of `1, 4, 6, 11`

ORIGINAL:

I am building a tool that will various record types (that come in as one column, many rows) and split them into columns (depending on certain values in the lines of data).

The data could look like this:

```
062017000JohnDoe   777E
```

It may be specified as (recordtype 2 chars; YYYY; three zeroes filler; Name; Filler Spaces; ID)

The delimiters are predefined based on the record type (defined by user) and subtype (often defined by the first 1 or 2 numbers in the data, depending on the record type).

I am using the .TextToColumns function like so:

```
DataToParse.TextToColumns Destination:=DataToParse, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
FieldInfo:=FieldInfoString, TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Earlier in the code, I build the string

```
FieldInfoString = "Array(Array(0,1), Array(5,1), Array(12,1))"
```

I build the string using concatenation, adding ", Array(x , 1)" for each delimiter (looping through a variable length list of x's).

The 'FieldInfoString' variable is throwing an error. What should go in the *FieldInfo* parameter is:

```
FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0,1), Array(5,1), Array(12,1))
```

The string is dynamically created for many different file types. **Is there a way to use this string to define the arrays for use in .TextToColumns?**

I also tried **altering my approach and dynamically building the array:**

```
Dim FieldInfoArray()

' Here there is code to define DelimitersToParse - which ends up being a 1 column by x rows 
' group of numbers that will be the first value in the arrays > i.e. Array(___, 1)

ReDim Preserve FieldInfoArray(DelimitersToParse.Rows.Count)
```

The first entry is (0,1)

```
FieldInfoArray(0) = Array(0,1)

        i = 1
        For Each ParsedDelimiter In DelimitersToParse.Cells
            FieldInfoArray(i) = Array(ParsedDelimiter.Value, 1)
            i = i + 1
        Next ParsedDelimiter

DataToParse.TextToColumns Destination:=DataToParse, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=FieldInfoArray, TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

The array approach doesn't throw an error, and the data is split, but not by any of the delimiters that I defined. I'm not sure how to audit **FieldInfoArray** to see what is going on.

EDIT: have attempted @jochen 's answer, auditing my array. still having issues - the 77777 should be placed in one column but is split as 777 | 77

[image: attempt at first answer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely edited after comment/edit:

Your Building approach is alright. You can loop to build an 0-based array with arrays using variables as you did above.

Enter a `stop`in the line before your `TextToColumns`to have a look at the values and structure of your array. Using some test values and a simple structure it worked perfectly with me:

```
Sub test()
Dim Arr()
Dim v1 As Integer, v2 As Integer
ReDim Arr(0 To 4)

    v1 = 2: v2 = 6
    Arr(0) = Array(0, 2)
    Arr(1) = Array(v1, 1)
    Arr(2) = Array(v2, 2)
    Arr(3) = Array(9, 2)
    Arr(4) = Array(19, 2)

    Range("A2").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A2"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Arr, _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

End Sub
```

EDIT:

As you are still encountering problems (now your code splits but not on the right positions as I understand) I give you another example.

In my example-sheet I have a Range called `Data` with Data in the structure of your provided example-data (062017000JohnDoe   777E). I have another Rangecalled `Delimiters` with a matrix of widths and types (I prefer to use Text in some cases, especially if I dont want to loose 0's and blanks. My Delimiter matrix (5 rows, 2 columns) looks like:

```
0     2
2     1
6     2
9     2
19    2
```

Then I use the following single-line-code to split `Data` into Columns:

```
    Range("Data").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Data"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Range("Delimiters").Value2, _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Comment: Yes - but the way the string is built is by appending ", Array( _ , 1)" for each delimiter that needs to be added (I don't just define the whole string at once, or I would use your approach). I am asking if I can take that string and convert it to the second code blurb in your answer

Comment: Edited original post for clarity

Comment: I've attempted to replicate, added a screenshot in my question. It still isn't giving me the correct delimiters despite the correct values being in place. 
I do use 1 as the second value in all of my arrays for now - I don't think the issue would stem from that but it could be (i.e. `Array(0,**1**)`

Comment: I am using the microsoft definition of the .texttocolumns method as my baseline in understanding the function. FieldInfo is discussed about 2/3 through
[link to microsoft method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213590(v=office.11).aspx)

Comment: frustrating...when I manually type it in a la 
`Array(Array(0,1), Array(5,1), Array(10,1))`
it works. I feel like this has to do with the way I'm building the array

Comment: strange. Are you doing multiple TextToColumns? I Edit my code to give you another example how to easily use TextToColumns.

Comment: Thank you! I am about to try this method. I did not realize I could pass a range to _FieldInfo_ To answer your question - yes, I am doing multiple TextToColumns, but the first one is only to remove the first or first two characters (which denote what the rest of the delimiters should be). This works fine. Then I re-set the target range (`DataToParse`) to the correct column (the remaining data) and attempt to do the second (final) split.

Comment: I believe I found my issue (and I am facepalming). I didn't realize the delimiters had to be _absolute_ rather than _incremental_ (for example, I was using
`1

3

2

3`
rather than
`1

4

6

9`